Makefile command for prepending and appending files to a passed .tex file
I have a rule in my Makefile like the following:
%: %.tex
    echo $@
    texify --pdf --synctex=1 --clean $@.tex

Whatever file that is passed, I'd like to prepend an existing file called fm.tex and append another existing file called bm.tex, but I would like to keep whatever the existing .tex filename that is the value of $@.tex so that the PDF generated will have that file name. I'm kind of just starting with creating Makefiles, so any help is greatly appreciated.
I've tried some various unix commands, but not getting what I need.

This doesn't seem like a makefile problem to me.  It seems like a texify issue.  Put another way, figure out how to get texify to do what you want for some command or set of commands typed in at the shell prompt, then put those commands into your makefile.  That algorithm shows it's not actually a makefile issue.  Only people who know what facilities texify provides, can help.  For example maybe it allows you to pass multiple filenames, and set the "name" specifically separately from the filename.  Or maybe it has --prepend/--postfix options or something.

I wouldn't use texify, this often hides useful debug information and makes diagnosing problems much more painful than it has to be.

Other tex automation tools, like latexmk, have options to prepend code to the compilation. Depending on what you are trying to do with fm.tex and bm.tex, you might be able to use -pretex to do the same.

It would not be hard but rather brittle to have make replace your actual input file, then put it back afterwards. A much better solution is to call your input file e.g. main_body.tex and leave it to make to construct main.tex from fm.tex, main_body.tex, and bm.tex, and be prepared to remove body.tex at any time, since it can be regenerated at will.

Your question sounds a bit like an xy-question. Maybe you could add a bit of background what you are trying to do?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Ordinarily I have a main .tex file that includes all the main topics as separate .tex files. I can build that entire doc as a PDF. It has been suggested that It might be desirable to create a standalone pdf for  any given .tex file. I would put any necessary preamble /postamble .tex source in the fm.tex and bm.tex, respectively, so that the combined files would be a complete .tex file. Does that make sense`

Have a look at the subfiles package. This way each file can be compiles one its own or included in the main file. No need to prepend or append anything.

Can you just use cat, or would that break the format?

Instead of coming up with complicate prepend/append solutions, simply use the subfiles package. This way you can compile the main file or the includes files individually.
There are other similar packages, but the advantage of subfiles is that you don't need to repeat the preamble. The subfiles can use the the preamble from the main file.
A short example:
Main file main.tex:
\documentclass{article}

% your packages, e.g.
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}

test

\subfile{cap1}

\end{document}

One of the chapters cap1.tex:
\documentclass[main]{subfiles}

% no packages necessary, macros from packages like `\textcolor` 
% will still work if they are loaded in the main file

\begin{document}

test \textcolor{red}{text}

\end{document}


That looks very straight forward, It's just that, whoever put our files together, put them all in one subdirectory, and each chapter/topic, has no preamble or postamble. It appears I'd have to do some editing on each file, before I could use this package.

Adding \documentclass[main]{subfiles}\begin{document} and \end{document} can probably be automated, maybe some sed wizard can help you with that if you ask a new question.

That has given me something to think about! Thanks!

When you call the .tex file with subfile{filename} do you NOT need the .tex extension?

Like for \input{...}, \include{...} etc. latex will usually assume some standard extensions. You probably can use the extension, but don't need to.

This seems to be working, but I can't get my header and footer to show up in the individual pdf file.  In my main.tex file, they are set after the begin{document} command, and it doesn't like if I move the \usepackages{subfiles} out of the preamble area.

btw, is there a way to turn off the section numbering when generating the standalone pdf?

@RussellUrquhartC You could redefine the section either in the preamble of the subfile or based on the jobname. Can you ask a new question?
